# Programming in VBA in Excel 2003

Tags: excel, vba, import, shift

I'm new to the visual basics language and would like some help in writing some codes. So I'm trying to write a program that imports data from a spreadsheet and shifts current data over. So I have a spreadsheet file with 3 sheets. I would first delete the data in the third and last sheet, then cut and copy the data from the second sheet over to the third sheet and the first to the second. and then prompt the user to select a data file to import to the first sheet. How do I go about doing this ????
Thanks

Comment: one way is `Selection.Cut` and `Selection.Paste`. If you post some code you already have, we can check it. Otherwise you need to do some research & tutorials first to give it try. It is best if you try something and ask for improvements, rather than asking for a total solution. Think of this as a learning opportunity.

Comment: @jerryh91: Please give your question a more specific title, and please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access each cell by using

```
Cells(row,column)
```

Where the row and column are both numeric.  You can set the values like this

```
Cell(row,column) = "This is a new value"
```

You can access the values like this

```
aString = cells(row,column)
```

If you want to copy data from one worksheet to another, this code will copy the first twenty six columns and rows from worksheet 2 to worksheet 3...

```
dim row as integer
dim column as integer

For column = 1 to 26
    For row = 1 to 26
        'Copy worksheet 3 value to worksheet 2's value
        Worksheets(3).cells(row,column)=Worksheets(2).cells(row,column)
        'Clear worksheet 2's values
        Worksheets(2).cells(row,column)=""
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply! Also suppose I would like to import a new data spreadsheet to update an existing tab in excel. How do I go about prompting the user to select this new file and then replacing the OLD tab with the new information??

Comment: There are two ways.  First, you can create a user form.  Go to Insert_>UserForm.  You can provide a place where the user may type in the path and file name.  This is not as user friendly, but is easily implemented.

The other option is to use a common dialog.  It is much nicer on the user, but you'll have to access an API.  That sounds scary, but it's easy enough to do.  Sample code can be found here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155724(v=office.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply delete the third sheet by executing:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkBook.Sheets(3).Delete
```

Then insert a new sheet and place it before Sheet 1 and 2

```
ActiveWrokBook.Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveWorkBook.Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = "The New Name of your newly inserted sheet"
```

Then fill the sheet with any data that you may want to. You did not include any details in your question about what is the source of the data, so I guess, you already know about that.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply! Also suppose I would like to import a new data spreadsheet to update an existing tab in excel. How do I go about prompting the user to select this new file and then replacing the OLD tab with the new information??

Comment: Do you want to open a Browse dialog for the user to select a file? Or do you want to ask him if he/she wants to update the the workbook with a pre-determinded workbook? The first solution is not straight forward, it needs a little hassle, but the second one is easy. you could do a simple "Application.Workbooks.Open filename.xls" and then you can either copy or cut a sheet from that workbook to the one already open. Too little space here to explain.